# How to insert a string in alphabetical order to a new array?

Tags: c#

I've been looking up a lot of videos, tried using the bubble sort method, insert sort method, but nothing seems to work for this particular problem. I am supposed to add a string (movie name) to an array, but I must do it alphabetically. I can not sort the array after it's completed, it must be done while I add the new strings.

I've seen a lot posts with similar questions like this but all of them sort the array after its completed!

Comment: Why do you need an array for this? I'm asking since array manipulation in C# is less efficient than in low level languages (e.g. you want realloc)..

Comment: Well, instead of giving you an answer, draw an empty array on paper and start inserting several strings in it. You will soon figure out you need to shift things to insert a string in it's proper spot.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.
Please take the [tour] to learn how Stack Overflow works and read [ask] on how to improve the quality of your question.
Then [edit] your question to include the source code you have as a [mcve], which can be compiled and tested by others.

Comment: i swear ive been drawing arrays for 2 days now. Give me another hint please! Right now my idea is: use a while loop to check my name is bigger than the one on my array UNTIL it finds one that is bigger than name. THEN insert my name before the bigger one and afer the smaller ones.

Comment: Well, you really can't *"insert into an array"*. Arrays are fixed length collections containing instance (or references to instances) of a single type. Other collection types (like `List<T>`) allow insertions; arrays not so much. To *insert* into an array, you'd need to shuffle all the elements after the insertion point down by one (start at the end if you are going to do this). To find where to insert, compare the new string to the existing elements. As soon as your string compares larger, you've found your insertion point. You won't get a full solution here until your question shows effort

Comment: Assuming the array has enough space to hold all the strings, your inserting algorithm would first need to figure out where in the array the new/next string has to be, and then move all strings from there on and out one space over to make room for the new string.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen is there a method such .push that would allow me to insert my new string and push the rest of the array?

Comment: No, there isn't, because that data structure is the `List<T>`, or `ArrayList` that we had before. There was/is no need to implement that kind of functionality on arrays because array sizes are immutable. However, simply loop from the last item down to where you intend to place your new string and move them up. You need to loop down from the last item to not overwrite items when you move/copy them up. If none of this makes sense then you really need to just start to try to implement it.

Comment: @Flydog57 im not asking a full solution, this is my homework i dont intend for you guys to do it for me. I understand what i need to do, but imagine i have 5 names already on my array, and i have a new one to "insert" and when i compare if its larger to my array's names, it finds that in the 2nd place its the where it should be. But then my algorithm stops, and what if there is another smaller name let's say in the 4th place? Also, my array is supposed to be 20 names long, what if i have to insert one in the 2nd place? How can i move all my names to the right?

Comment: Create an array of, say, 20 elements. Create a variable called curentSize When you do an insert, iterate over the array, looking for the first "larger" element. If yo uh get to the currentSize-th element, add the entry at the end and increment currentSize. If not, remember where you want to put it. Then, starting at the end (at currentSize), iterate down towards 0, copying each element up one in the array, till you get to your insertion spot. Put your new element there and increment currentSize. For bonus points, put this all in a class `class InsertableSizedArray<T>` where T is IComparable

Comment: If your initial capacity is 20, after 20 insertions, you run out. At that point (if you've wrapped this in a class), create a new array twice as long, copy all the elements into the new array, and continue to party

Comment: @Flydog57 im gonna smash my brains out

Comment: Try this on paper first, with five elements. It will make more sense then.

Comment: Read all the comments-the algorithm is there. Then write 5 or 6 simple strings on very small pieces of paper. Get a bigger piece of paper, and draw 10 slots on it, each big enough to hold on small piece. Shuffle the small papers and start putting them into the slots. Don't take short cuts (like putting your hand on three papers and moving them as a group; do everything one at a time). Follow my (and others) instructions, it should work. Only once you've figured it out, start writing code. If you get stuck, post the code you have and ask a question

Comment: @le0nicolas you can try a kind of this solution: https://dotnetfiddle.net/gLhE3M

Answer (score 1):

Here is a couple of methods that might help you.

```
private void PrintAlphabetically()
{
    string[] movies = new string[5];
    movies[0] = "b";
    movies[1] = "x";
    movies[2] = "m";
    movies[3] = "a";
    movies[4] = "t";
    AddToStringArray(ref movies, "s");
    Array.Sort(movies, (x, y) => String.Compare(x , y));
    for (int i = 0; i < movies.Length; i++)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(movies[i]);
    }
}

private void AddToStringArray(ref string[] array, string item)
{
    List<string> list = array.OfType<string>().ToList();
    list.Add(item);
    array = list.ToArray();
}
```

Comment: thanks for your response, but sadly i must only work with 1 array. And i cant have the array already filled. I must add each particular string, and everytime i must do it in alphabetical order. Thanks for taking your time tho, and treating me nicely, not like the others lol